# Can I connect the LoRa Module pin to SMA Antenna with wire?

Tags: connector, antenna, lora

I have **RFM95W LoRa Module** and an antenna with an SMA connector (you can see in the image below). The module does not have an SMA connector. There are just pins. Can I connect the SMA connector with some wire soldering to the LoRa module? Will this make any communication problem?
[image]

Comment: um, I hope this isn't about sending video data to a model satellite as your previous question covered, but commands only?

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes, this is not for video sending. This module will just send/receive commands and some of the telemetry data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not ideal but if you keep the connections as short as possible then the losses will be minimised.  You could use a short length of 50-ohm coax, although that would probably be no better since you'd have two connections rather than one.  Electrically the best option would be to solder the SMA connector directly onto the module, although mechanically you might prefer to mount the connector rigidly and then use some very short wires (5mm).  Normal hook-up wire will be ok, you don't need anything special.